# Pug "Each" Iteration not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, pug

So my problem is the `each` iteration in pug print only the end of the object

Here is my code

```
-
  let boxes = {
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-01.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-02.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-03.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-04.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-05.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-06.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-07.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"},
    "Test Title": {img: "img/articles/image-08.jpg", p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"}
  }
.articles#articles
  .main-title Articles
  .container
      each value, key in boxes
        .box
          .image
            img(src=value.img)
          .text
            h3 #{key}
            p #{value.p}
          .more
            a Read more
            i.fas.fa-long-arrow-alt-right
```

The Output

```
<div class="articles" id="articles">
<div class="main-title">Articles</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image"><img src="img/articles/image-08.jpg"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Test Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="more"><a>Read more</a><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I Expect iteration of 8 boxes not only one box

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put some different titles in and try it, an object can't have duplicate properties. e.g. declaring `{"test": 1, "test": 2}` results in a `{"test": 2}` object because the "test" property is overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a change in the **object** and in the **h3** of each. This way the iteration works.

```
-
  let boxes = [
    {
    name: "Test Title A",
    img: "img/articles/image-01.jpg",
    p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"
    },
    {
    name: "Test Title B",
    img: "img/articles/image-01.jpg",
    p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit."
    },
    {
    name: "Test Title C",
    img: "img/articles/image-01.jpg",
    p: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit"
    },
    ]
  
.articles#articles
  .main-title Articles
  hr
  .container
    each value, key in boxes
      .box
        .image
          img(src=value.img)
        .text
          h3 #{value.name}
          p #{value.p}
        .more
          a Read more
          i.fas.fa-long-arrow-alt-right
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).